# python scrabble word scorer

Tags: python

i have been asked to write a program that allows a user to enter a word and calculates the value of that word. So, ‘Hello’ would have a value of 8. If a user needs to enter a double or triple letter score they enter the value after the letter e.g. if the first ‘L’ of ‘hello’ was a double letter score they would enter ‘hel2lo’.

```
score = "a": 1, "c": 3, "b": 3, "e": 1, "d": 2, "g": 2, 
     "f": 4, "i": 1, "h": 4, "k": 5, "j": 8, "m": 3, 
     "l": 1, "o": 1, "n": 1, "q": 10, "p": 3, "s": 1, 
     "r": 1, "u": 1, "t": 1, "w": 4, "v": 4, "y": 4, 
     "x": 8, "z": 10}
```

this is all i have so far. i dont know how to do it :(

Comment: All you have so far is a `SyntaxError`.

Comment: "I don't know how to do it" isn't the kind of question Stack Overflow can answer for you. Please read the help.

Comment: Also, you've tagged this with both "python" and "basic". Does this mean you're looking for an answer in either of those two languages? (That would be odd, but given that what you have so far isn't legal in either language…)

Comment: would u give me an example of what i have to do?

Comment: @NikiDogra: Break the problem down into pieces. Write the pieces you know how to write, faking the parts you don't know how to write. Then you can ask a question saying, "I'm stuck on this part here, where I just wrote `multiplier = 2` because when I try to multiply `score` by the actual character `'2'` or `'3'` I get `'2222'` instead of `6` for some reason". Then someone can explain why you get that, and how to fix it, and how to write the real code that goes there.

Answer (score 0):

```
def score(word, points):
    counts26555731 = {}
    for iGotThisFromStackOverflow,char in enumerate(word):
        if char.isdigit():
            counts26555731[word[iGotThisFromStackOverflow-1]] += int(char)-1
            continue
        if char not in counts26555731:
            counts26555731[char] = 0
        counts26555731[char] += 1
    return sum(points[char]*count for char,count in counts26555731.items())
```

Usage:

```
points = {"a": 1, "c": 3, "b": 3, "e": 1, "d": 2, "g": 2, 
     "f": 4, "i": 1, "h": 4, "k": 5, "j": 8, "m": 3, 
     "l": 1, "o": 1, "n": 1, "q": 10, "p": 3, "s": 1, 
     "r": 1, "u": 1, "t": 1, "w": 4, "v": 4, "y": 4, 
     "x": 8, "z": 10}

word = 'hel2lo'
print(word, "is worth", score(word, points), "points")
```

This prints:

```
hel2lo is worth 9 points
```

Comment: Some people like to downvote any answer to a "gimme the codez" question because it encourages help vampires. Personally, I considered an upvote for naming one of your variables `iGotThisFromStackOverflow`, and if you could find a way to hide the URL of this answer I'd definitely do it. :)

Comment: @abarnert: check it out: I hid the post ID in a variable. Any prof/TA to google that variable should be led right here

Comment: For some reason, searching didn't turn it up before, but after I made a minor edit, I can now find it on SO search, and I'll bet searching even just `counts26555731` on Google will work in a few hours too. Nice trick.

Answer (score 0):

I have an alternative which uses `try/except` *KeyError*:

```
# by the way, you missed the { 
score = {
    "a": 1, "c": 3, "b": 3, "e": 1, "d": 2, "g": 2, 
    "f": 4, "i": 1, "h": 4, "k": 5, "j": 8, "m": 3, 
    "l": 1, "o": 1, "n": 1, "q": 10, "p": 3, "s": 1, 
    "r": 1, "u": 1, "t": 1, "w": 4, "v": 4, "y": 4, 
    "x": 8, "z": 10
}

def check_score(word):
    total = 0
    for n, letter in enumerate(word):
        try:
            # look up dictionary and add paired score to total
            total += score[letter]
        # if letter is digit, above will throw KeyError
        except KeyError:
            # as previous letter score is added, add (int(letter) - 1) times of score
            total += score[word[n-1]] * (int(letter) - 1)
    print "Total scores for {}: {}".format(word, total)
```

---

```
check_score('hel2lo')
Total scores for hel2lo: 9
```